# How to burn a BLU-RAY disc in a DVD-R?

Tags: dvd, blu-ray

I have a BLU-RAY disc of my project. I need rip this to my HD and burn this content in a DVD-R. Its possible?

Comment: Do you have a BLU-RAY reader? Do you have a DVD Burner?

Answer (score 2):

No. A Blu-Ray disc is a much more dense type of disc. It can hold a lot more data than a DVD can. If the total amount of data you have on a Blu-Ray is less than the amount of data that can be fit on a DVD, then it would be possible. However, you cannot read a Blu-Ray disc without a drive made to read them. If you haven't got a Blu-Ray drive, you won't be able to get any data off a Blu-Ray disc, and onto your computer.

Comment: Very thanks for information. Anyway, no have possible to burn a bluray project in a dvd. The solution is buy again in dvd or buy a bluray drive - i don´t have it.

Answer (score 2):

What sort of data are we talking about? Whichever, the answer is yes.

If it's video, sure. You can use something like MakeMKV/Handbrake to get the video from the disc and then something like Brasero or K9Copy to create the new DVD. You'll lose quality but there you go.

If we're talking about files then there's really no option to reduce their size significantly but you should be able to break them up into multiple files. If you have files that are too large to fit on a single disc, there are tools like `hjsplit` that will allow you to dismantle them, put them on disc, copy them off discs at the other end and then reassemble.

Comment: A video-data. The bluray is a movie created by my family, burned in a bluray disc by my uncle. But, the most people of family no have a bluray player or bluray reader in computer. I looked this software (handbrake) and its amazing. I try it after my job. Thanks!